# (C++) Decrypting a custom Polybius square

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm working on a project related to a cryptography systems, and I need some help. Here's the related code: [Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRuNlanDAhQYVKePeryxZC1WaqirALrQtmj_3dmEZMCR0cNjBalTIYAiZu4B3-tAU3Jh7CRugIm7d0U/pub)

This is just a main part related to encryption. My goal is to make encryption **and** decryption. But I'm stuck with the decryption. 
My only idea was to decrypt it through the switch-case construction, but it's kinda stupid, right?

So, do you have any ideas what do I need to add to make it decryptable without much CPU and RAM usage?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is my first question here, so if I've made something wrong - sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The hardcoded way, using a dictionary (map) or hash table (unordered_map) works. In cryptography it is not uncommon to hardcode tables of data.

You already hardcoded an array for encryption. If you use a hash table or dictionary, that can work both for encryption and decryption, requiring a single one.

Comment: Hmm, as for me it divides my numbers properly. Like this:
Input: HEY *line ends*
15 *line ends*
18 *line ends*
41 *line ends*
EDIT: Strange formatting is used there, need to get used to it.

Comment: I'll try to hardcode it through the dictionary, probably. Thanks!